# Warning when value is not changed by the conversion

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

Consider this program:

```
int main() {
  int ju = 1;
  short ki = ju;
  return ki;
}
```

Compiling yields a warning:

```
conversion to ‘short int’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   short ki = ju;
              ^
```

However according [to the docs](//gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> Do not warn [...] if the value is not changed by the conversion like in
>   "abs (2.0)".

We are dealing with the value of `1`, which can be easily stored in `int` or
`short`. The value is not changed by the conversion, so why the warning?

Comment: Your code does not contain an explicit cast, merely an implicit one.

Comment: The compiler is issuing a general warning - "may" alter its value. You can't expect the compiler to keep track off what value may or may not be in the variable.

Comment: `ju` is an `int`, regardless of the fact that you are assigning `1` to it. So a conversion is required.

Comment: That is a different issue, where arithmetic is done on a `char` operand. in this case, suppose the value of `ju` is supplied by a function, or a user input?

Comment: @Siguza There is no such thing an an *implicit cast*. There are: a cast which is an explicit conversion, and an implicit conversion which isn't a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring any possible compiler optimizations:

```
int main() {
  int ju = 1;
  short ki = ju; /* Compiler won't [probably] make use of (without optimizations) what the value of ju is at runtime */
  return ki;
}
```

Another example (even with compiler optimizations, it's not possible to determine what the value of `ju` will be when it's assigned to `ki` at compile time):

```
int foo() {
  int ju = 1;
  short ki = 1;

  scanf("%d", &ju);

  ki = ju; /* (Compiler will issue the warning) What's the value of ju? Will it fit in ki? */

  return ki; /* Another implicit conversion, this one from short to int, which the compiler won't issue any warning */
}
```

The compiler cannot know what's the value of `ju`, so it correctly warns about an implicit type conversion.

Regarding the documentation, and quoting from your question:

> Do not warn [...] if the value is not changed by the conversion like
>   in "abs (2.0)".

```
int foo() {
  return 0UL;
}
```

This is an example how a value will not change, regardless of the types involved. Zero will always be zero, being it a `int` or `unsigned long` type.

Or,

```
int foo() {
  return 2.0; /* Same case as abs(2.0), an implicit float to int convertion, whose values are not changed by doing so. */
}
```

So, basically, this only applies to literals (such as the `abs(2.0)` example given in the docs).

Comment: @Sierra : I think you've missed the context of that doc quote.

Comment: The compiler can and does "know" *exactly* what the value of `ju` is in the original code. Whether it uses this knowledge is another matter. In the general case, the sentence "Ignoring any possible compiler optimizations" does not make sense; a compiler is free to compile a program any way it wants to as long as the observable behavior is preserved (as I am sure you are aware). I am not sure whether gcc gives any explicit guarantees to compile a source in a specific way with `-O0`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I understand your point, but since it's not part of the specification what optimizations flags do or not, we cannot also say that a compiler does or does not know at any given time (unless, of course, we do know exacty what it does based on documenation). The given example along with the second example is a merely illustration of what `gcc` determines in both cases (being the first pointing to a `not knowing the value of` fallback).

Comment: For the sake of simplicity and to avoid long discussions based on ambiguous terms, lets also define `know` as `make use of`

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider : Regarding `does know exactly what the value of ju` & `Whether it uses this knowledge is another matter`. It almost always *doesn't* use this knowledge with the default compilation options.

Answer (score 0):

```
short ki = ju;
```

falls under

> implicit conversions that may alter a value [1].

An `int` is *almost* always greater than `short` in regard to the number of bits is can store. This is known compile-time.

> The VALUE is not changed by the conversion, so why the warning?

This is a conclusion you've made from your instinct. This knowledge even if known need not[2] be used compile-time.

**Reference**

[[ 1 ]](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) gcc Warning Options.

**Note**

[2 ] A compiler need not keep track of values stored in a variable.

Comment: @Sierra `short ju = 1; int ki = ju;` is a case that would not issue a warning.

Comment: Your example is a counter argument to your own answer. It relies on the arrangment of types rather than the value, which by your own admission is not known at compile time

Comment: @Sierra, You've deleted the previous comments. So comment#1 doesn't make much sense at the moment.

Comment: Still my example stands correct because, the point that I was trying to make was that the warning was entirely based on type and had nothing to do with the value at all

Comment: "This is NOT[2] known compile-time" is simply not true; it's capitalized wrongness. The value is known to the compiler as well as it is to us. For example compilers these days use the fact if a variable is used uninitialized, causing UB, and eliminate whole code paths based on that, and hoppefully warn about it. They usually know better than humans what value(s) the language memory model permits for a variable at any given location in the code, based on possible code re-orderings etc. If you mean instead "does not use the known value to eliminate a senseless warning", then say so.

Comment: With respect to what compilers do or don't do with the given information: That changes over time. gcc today does different things than gcc 20 years ago with the same code, on default.

Comment: Huh, really ? These are the comments - `Will it fit in ki?` & `Another implicit conversion, this one from short to int,` & `The compiler cannot know what's the value of ju, so it correctly warns about an implicit type conversion.` from the other answer. The warning you got  in question is based entirely on type.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider : I just put the word NOT not to end up in a big sentence and thought the note at the end would clear the confusion for that. I have reworded if that was ambiguous.